# Возможно ли улучшить генерацию `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` для списка столбцов? (большое количество столбцов)

Tags: python, mysql

Есть табличка с большим количеством столбцов, первым идет столбец ID типа INT со свойствами Unique и Primary.

Хочу добавить или обновить строки в таблице.

Вроде как удалось собрать работающую конструкцию через `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, успешно вставляющую и обновляющую строки, но грызет, что может быть, я где то затупил и можно как то оптимальнее/лучше?:

```
# columns_list = [], сделанный из "select column_name from information_schema.columns..."
columns_update = (
                   ", ".join(f"{col} = VALUE({col})" if ind > 0 else ""
                             for ind, col in enumerate(columns_list))
                 )[2:]
# Я собираюсь обновлять все столбцы кроме столбца ID, который идет под индексом 0,
# через `[2:]` я обрезал первый лишний `, `, появившийся из за `else ""`

insert_update_query = f"INSERT INTO table_name ({', '.join(columns_list)}) " \
                      f"VALUES ({('%s, ' * number_of_columns)[:-2]}) " \
                      f"ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE {columns_update};"

cursor.executemany(insert_update_query, rows)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: Не могли бы Вы раскрыть смысл сего действа? Просто я подозреваю, что поскольку имя таблицы Вы не меняете, есть более простой и правильный путь решения Вашей задачи.

Comment: `replace into` пробовали ?

Comment: Есть QTableWidget, хочу изменения в нем отправлять обратно в таблицу @Namerek

Comment: Надо бы почитать @n1tr0xs

Comment: *первым идет столбец ID типа INT со свойствами Unique и Primary.* Ну если PRIMARY - то однозначно UNIQUE, можно было не упоминать... *как удалось собрать работающую конструкцию через `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`* Уникальность по первичному ключу - это **единственное** ограничение уникальности в таблице? Если нет - то REPLACE INTO сгенерирует новый автоинкремент, что может быть нежелательным ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bj8W1NOz)).

Comment: @Akina единственный, при том без автоинкремента.

Comment: Тогда @n1tr0xs предложил идеальное решение.